# Prepend character in URL?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

In a sub directory on my apache server, I have a PHP program `index.php` and nothing else. My domain `example.com` resolves to this subdir, but I want to capture the full value after the `/` and pass it to the PHP program, so users won't have to type `?`.

How it is now:

```
example.com/abc -> www/subdir/abc
```

What I want:

```
example.com/abc -> www/subdir/?val=abc
```

So that when a user types

```
http://example.com/abc
```

he will get results from

```
http://example.com/?val=abc
```

How do I prepend `?val=` using the `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put this code in your htaccess (which has to be located next to `index.php`)

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /?val=$1 [L]
```